# Git checkout deletes website uploads

Tags: git, repository, web-deployment

I am using Git for simple website development and deployment.

I develop on localhost, pushing my changes to the server which deploys the web to the corresponding directory via posthook and

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/website/httpdocs/ git checkout -f
```

My problem is that all user uploads on the live server (uploaded by the website users or via backend) get deleted which live in

```
/var/www/website/httpdocs/assets/uploads
```

How can I keep these files when automatically checking out/deploying the web without tracking them in my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is move your user upload directory outside webroot and symlink from webroot to the user upload directory.

For reference:
https://serverfault.com/questions/147185/website-deployment-managing-user-uploaded-content

Comment: that seems like a nice solution. i will try that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to *not* track them at all.

Try adding this to your `.gitignore` file:

```
assets/uploads/*
```

Comment: I already added this line to my .gitignore file, working just fine, but that is not my problem. My problem is: There are already files in the folder where I check my repository out/deploy to, that must not be deleted (uploaded by users on the website).

Comment: So when your hook `checkout`s the repo, it is overwriting files that aren't in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, use git stash and git stash pop.

Comment: I edited my answer to make my problem a bit clearer. It is not about my local files, but the files uploaded via the website itself (user content).